Perl autoconverts the '&' character to '\u0026' in a JSON link
Using the LWP library, I receive JSON data, where the link looks like:

param1=&param2=&param3=

When you pull out the value of the link along the way, for some reason pearl replaces the & symbol with \u0026.
What to do?
I tried to remove characters by replacing them with regular expressions, but the %5c' character still appears.

For what it's worth, \u0026 is a perfectly legit JSON encoding for &. Can you show how you are using LWP to get and decode JSON?

To be clear, are you sending the 'link' (URL) to get data, or are you receiving (JSON) data that contains the 'link' (URL)?

Problem solved, thanks
